# Find the sum of the series $S = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{k^{4} + k^{2} + 1} $

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$ S = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{k}{k^{4} + k^{2} + 1} $$

I started by factorizing the denominator as $k^2+k+1$ and $k^2-k+1$
The numerator leaves a quadratic with $k$ and $k-1$ or a constant with $k+1$ and $k-1.$
I tried writing the individual terms, ofcourse, it was useless.
How do I do this?

Comment: After you factor the denominator and use partial fractions, I believe the sum will telescope.

Comment: As a rule, we don't use $\sum_{n=1}^{n}$. We use two different variables: $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dots$. Also, you *really don't need any of those parantheses.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2449134/how-to-evaluate-the-sum-sum-k-1n-frackk41-4/2450835

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So your term is equal to $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k^2-k+1}-\frac{1}{k^2+k+1}\right)$$

Now note $(k+1)^2-(k+1)+1=k^2+k+1$, so your term is: $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k^2-k+1}-\frac{1}{(k+1)^2-(k+1)+1}\right)$$

and you can apply a telescoping series technique to establish the sum to $n$ is just half of $\frac{1}{1^2 -1 +1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2-(n+1)+1}$. And if you are also looking for the limit, half of $\frac{1}{1^2 -1 +1}$.

Comment: Note that if you didn't recognize that $(k+1)^2-(k+1)+1=k^2+k+1$, you can discover it by noticing that the roots of $x^2-x+1=0$ - namely, $\frac12(1\pm\sqrt{-3})$ - are exactly 1 more than the roots of $x^2+x+1=0$, $\frac12(-1\pm\sqrt{-3})$.